# Загрузка скрипта с произвольными параметрами

Tags: javascript, html

Есть html-страница, на которой имеется поле ввода и кнопка. Есть скрипт, который принимает параметры:

```
<script
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=someKey&libraries=geometry">
</script>
```

Задача: импортировать скрипт с параметрами из поля ввода по нажатию кнопки. Возможно ли так сделать, и если да, то как?

Comment: Задача... непонятная. Каким образом можно "импортировать скрипт с параметрами"? В каком виде должны эти параметры фигурировать в скрипте? Предустановленные переменные? В общем, что такое `скрипт, который принимает параметры`?

Comment: Никита, напишите на обычном языке что вам нужно сделать, к примеру При вводе имени в поле, после клика по кнопе Продолжить должно происходить то-то, то-то, а иначе вообще не понятно чего вы ходите добиться.

Comment: @RifmaMan

Вот есть тэг
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=someKey&libraries=geometry"></script>

Мне нужно, чтобы он исполнился с ключом из поля ввода. В конечном итоге мне надо использовать методы из библиотеки geometry.

Comment: @NikitaNesmiyanov теперь задача ясна, но к сожалению у меня не было опыта в динамической подгрузке библиотек js, они ведь загружаются разово со страницей. Может вам стоит открывать после этого новую вкладку или окно, в котором уже будет вставлен url на js скрипт с ключом пользователя (но это лишь предположение) и там отрисововать карту.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var scriptUrl  = document.getElementById('script-url'), 
    scriptPrms = document.getElementById('script-params'), 
    btnAdd     = document.getElementById('add'); 

btnAdd.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (!scriptUrl.value.length)
    return; 
  let scriptEl = document.createElement('script'); 
  scriptEl.addEventListener('load', function () {
    alert(`Скрипт\n${this.src}\nзагружен.`); 
  }); 
  scriptEl.addEventListener('error', function () {
    alert(`Не удалось подключить скрипт\n${this.src}`); 
  }); 
  scriptEl.src = scriptUrl.value + (scriptPrms.value.length ? `?${scriptPrms.value}` : ''); 
  document.body.appendChild(scriptEl); 

  displayScriptsHtml(); 
});

function displayScriptsHtml() {
  let htmlView = document.getElementById('html-view'), 
      scripts  = document.body.querySelectorAll('script'); 
  htmlView.textContent = ''; 
  for (let i = 1; i < scripts.length; i++)
    htmlView.textContent += `${scripts[i].outerHTML}\n`; 
}
```

```css
label, input, button { font: 16px sans-serif; }
label { display: inline-block; margin-bottom: 0.3em; }

     #script-url { width: 350px; }
  #script-params { width: 260px; }
#add, #html-view { width: 390px; }

#html-view {
  display: block; box-sizing: border-box; 
  min-height: 8em; overflow: auto; 
  margin-top: 16px; padding: 0.5em; 
  background-color: #444; color: #eee; 
  white-space: pre; font: 10px monospace; 
}
```

```html
<label>URL: <input id="script-url" type="text" value="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" placeholder="https://example.com/filename.js"></label><br>
<label>GET-параметры: <input id="script-params" type="text" value="key=someKey&libraries=geometry" placeholder="foo=1&bar=42"></label><br>
<button id="add">Добавить</button>

<div id="html-view"></div>
```